# GDB for MacOs no more special or no more supported?

Tags: macos, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I found that in Eclipse CDT 4.5.2 (8.8) in the class `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.launching.LaunchUtils` there was a constant `MACOS_GDB_MARKER` that no longer exists in eclipse CDT 4.6.3 (9.2.1). I want to know why. Is there no more difference between GDB for MacOS and others ? Is GDB for MacOs no more supported ? Is the constant "hidden" in another class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. As explain [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn90#Removal_of_support_for_the_old_Apple_GDB) and [there](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486148), The specific GDB produced by Apple is no more updated by Apple. So the CDT team decided to remove its support from CDT.